# Accessing JSON Information: Objects in Objects

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a JSON object that has a JSON object inside of it. It looks as follows:

```
{ 
  "skuInformation": {
     "hidden": "No",
     "description": "Glass Zipper Bags",
     "velocityClass": "Fast Mover",
     "currentCatalog": "Yes",
     "discontinued": "No",
     "sku": "1861900" 
  }
}
```

I need the access to the individual information inside of this object through JavaScript, but I'm having trouble trying to access it.

I have a function that parses this JSON object and is returned as jsonResponse. Let's say I needed sku description. I've tried console.log with `jsonResponse.description`, `jsonResponse[0].description`, and `Object.keys(jsonResponse)[0].description`. None of those work, all returning undefined. How do I gain access to the key-values inside of the JSON object?

Comment: You need to use it like this `jsonResponse.skuInformation.description`

Comment: The one you missed was `console.log(jsonResponse)` ;)

Comment: Gerardo Furtado is right. It's not a valid json.

Comment: Can someone please clarify why this is not valid json. I test it using jsonlint and it showed valid

Comment: It's a valid JS object, but JSON is a collection of objects with string keys and multi-type values. ex. `[{"foo": "bar", "boo": 1, "far": {"nested": 3}}]`

Comment: @Seth, that is what we have here. String keys, and we see two different value types (JSON and string). I agree with user2181397, this looks like a valid JSON object to me (and consequently a valid JS Object too). http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate/cb2d75c5

Comment: It's too late to edit my comment. But you're correct, that is a valid JSON object. However, I think the JSON responses that people here are referring to are collections (an array of objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have parsed your [JSON string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) into a [JavaScript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), you can access nested objects using the `.` syntax:

```
var jsonResponse = {"skuInformation":{"hidden":"No","description":"Glass Zipper Bags","velocityClass":"Fast Mover","currentCatalog":"Yes","discontinued":"No","sku":"1861900"}};

var description = jsonResponse.skuInformation.description;
console.log(description); // Glass Zipper Bags
```

As an alternative, you can also access it using the bracket syntax `[]` with the key as a string:

```
var key = 'skuInformation';
var description = jsonResponse[key].description;
```

[More about working with objects from MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.parse(json)['skuInformation']['description'];
```

JSON is a text format.

JavaScript objects are JavaScript objects (and not JSON).

Comment: You can remove the wrapping parentheses and use dots